# MVC AD search - Displaying multiple results as .cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, razor, active-directory

I have fully working code that searches active directory and displays it with MVC .cshtml But I have been trying to figure out away to add all the users found to a list then display them. As currently it just displays the first user found.

This is the HomeController that takes a value, Searches AD and returns the results.

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel profile)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //List<Principal> users = new List<Principal>();
                using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
                {
                    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
                    qbeUser.DisplayName = profile.Name + "*";

                    using (PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser))
                    {
                        if(!(srch.FindAll().Count() < 0))
                        {
                            foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
                            {
                                //users.Add(found);
                                IndexViewModel returnmodel = new IndexViewModel(found);

                                return View(returnmodel);
                            }
                        }                       
                    }
                }                               
            }
            return View(profile);
        }
   }
```

The IndexViewModel

```
public class IndexViewModel
    {

        public IndexViewModel(Principal found)
        {
            Name = found.DisplayName;
            Email = found.UserPrincipalName;
            Description = found.Description;

        }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
        [Display(Name = "Persons Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        //public List<Principal> user { get; set; }

    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
    <div id="content">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
    {


        <fieldset>

            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:280px" }, })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">

                </div>

            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
    <br>
</div>
    <table id="historyTable" class="table">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.Name</td>
            <td>@Model.Email</td>
            <td>@Model.Description</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT-----------**
**This is one method I tried ----------------**

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel profile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<Principal> users = new List<Principal>();
            using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
                qbeUser.DisplayName = profile.Name + "*";

                using (PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser))
                {
                    if(!(srch.FindAll().Count() < 0))
                    {
                        foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
                        {
                            users.Add(found);
                            IndexViewModel returnmodel = new IndexViewModel(users);
                            return View(returnmodel);
                        }
                    }                       
                }
            }                               
        }
        return View(profile);
    }
```

**IndexViewModel.cs**

```
public class IndexViewModel
{

    public IndexViewModel(List<Principal> found)
    {
        user = found;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
    [Display(Name = "Persons Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Principal> user { get; set; }

}
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="content">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
    {


        <fieldset>

            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:280px" }, })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">

                </div>

            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
    <br>
</div>
    <table id="historyTable" class="table">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
        @foreach (Principal prin in Model.user)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@prin.DisplayName</td>
                <td>@prin.UserPrincipalName</td>
                <td>@prin.Description</td>
             </tr>
        }        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The error I get on compile is --

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
Line 37:     <tbody>
Line 38:         @using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
Line 39:         @foreach (Principal prin in Model.user)
Line 40:         {
Line 41:             <tr>
```

Source File:  C:\Users\hga\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Intra AD people searcher\Intra AD people searcher\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    Line:  39

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC: How do you give a viewmodel a list and correctly output it on .cshtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507008/mvc-how-do-you-give-a-viewmodel-a-list-and-correctly-output-it-on-cshtml)

Answer (score 1):

You can add if statement to check for null

```
@if(Model.user !=null)
{
   @foreach (Principal prin in Model.user)
     {
         <!--your code here-->
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, your return statement is inside your foreach loop. So the first time it goes through the loop, it will return. That means you will only have one result.

Try this:

```
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
   users.Add(found);
}

IndexViewModel returnmodel = new IndexViewModel(users);
return View(returnmodel);
```